# Global variable is NULL in class method

Tags: php

My first line in my script I have:

```
$db = new db_class();
```

This is just an example to start the db object. Then I have:

```
class main {

    function init() {
        $this->session_start();
    }

    protected function session_start() {
        $sh = new session_handler();
        session_set_save_handler(
            array (& $sh, 'open'),
            array (& $sh, 'close'),
            array (& $sh, 'read'),
            array (& $sh, 'write'),
            array (& $sh, 'destroy'),
            array (& $sh, 'gc')
        );        
    }

}
```

All of the problems are in the in `session_handler` class. This code:

```
public function write($id, $data) {
    global $db;  

    var_dump($db); //returns NULL
}
```

says that `$db` is `NULL` instead of an instance of `db_class`.

Note, `db_class` objects work except when calling the `write()` method:

```
class main {

    function init() {
        global $db;

        var_dump($db); //returns the db object correctly

        $this->session_start();
    }

    protected function session_start() {
        $sh = new session_handler();
        session_set_save_handler(
            array (& $sh, 'open'),
            array (& $sh, 'close'),
            array (& $sh, 'read'),
            array (& $sh, 'write'),
            array (& $sh, 'destroy'),
            array (& $sh, 'gc')
        );  
    }

}
```

Comment: What it says when you var_dump just below this code of line `$db = new $db_class();
`?

Comment: Why you use the globals, it would be much better if you pass in the db instance into class.

Comment: $db=new $db_class() should be $db= new db_class() shoudn't it?

Comment: the db object, its working any where else

Comment: @jurka i cant use php version > 5.2

Comment: @Somesh Mukherjee i said this is just exaple the db object work great in any function as a globals instead of this

Comment: Is the db class being instantiated when you call the main() class? As already suggested, why not passing the object to the main() class, or instantiating the db class there, instead? You could also go for an autoloading function, I think

Comment: ican't do that because it will cause main - user_class - main - db -feach

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing the full global scope. You or your script is probably overwriting $db at some place. That's why you dont use globals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527

Comment: I don't know that this question makes any sense. This (minus the `$db_class()`, which the OP indicated was a typo) seems to work: http://codepad.org/pyOtgVJ8

Comment: i'm using php 5.2 and i can not upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is at first line
    $db = new $db_class();

if guess it should be like

```
$db = new db_class();
```

Or make sure that $db_class has value of class name that you wish to initialize

How about trying something like this

```
class main{
protected $_db;

function init($db){
    $this->_db = $db;
    $this->session_start();
}

protected function session_start() {
    $sh = new session_handler();
    session_set_save_handler(
        array (& $sh, 'open'),
        array (& $sh, 'close'),
        array (& $sh, 'read'),
        array (& $sh, 'write'),
        array (& $sh, 'destroy'),
        array (& $sh, 'gc')
    );        
}
public function write($id, $data) {
    vardump($this->_db);
}
}
```

Comment: no its not the problem because this is just example its started and work anywhere

Comment: this is not the problem i'm sure